# A simple gnuplot digitizer?

Tags: gnuplot

Sometimes it might be useful to digitize scanned graphs to get the data and redraw a plot.
I'm aware that there are dedicated tools with a lot of features, e.g. see miscellaneous links on the gnuplot home page: http://gnuplot.info/links.html

However, is there maybe a way using gnuplot only? Maybe with a few lines of code you can implement a simple version of a digitizer? Which should already be sufficient for some cases having a limited number of datapoints.

(**edit**: part of original question now put as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this might be useful to someone... this gnuplot version is just for fun, sharing and for demonstration of gnuplot capabilities.
Improvements are welcome, e.g.

- logarithmic axes, time axes, multiple curves, tilted images, etc.

**How it works:**

- an image is imported into a graph. gnuplot supports e.g. GIF, JPG, PNG. To see the list of filetypes `show datafile binary filetype`.
- the first 3 mouseclicks have to be on 1) end of y-axis, 2) origin, and 3) end of x-axis
- further mouseclicks draw datapoints

The following key bindings are implemented:

- **0**: (re-)define the axes from end of y-axis to origin to end of x-axis
- **x**: remove all datapoints
- **c**: clear only last datapoint
- **s**: save data to file

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.2.0)

```
### a simple gnuplot digitizer
reset session
 
IMAGE    = 'Superconductivity.png'
DATAFILE = 'Superconductivity.dat'
 
AxisXStart = 4.00
AxisXEnd   = 4.40
AxisYStart = 0.00
AxisYEnd   = 0.15

DataHeader = "# x-value y-value
set print $Data
    print DataHeader
set print

AxesHeader = "# axes mouse coordinates
set print $Axes
    print AxesHeader
set print

set margins 0,0,0,0
set key noautotitle

fx(point) = (word(point,1)-word($Axes[3],1))/(word($Axes[4],1)-word($Axes[3],1))*(AxisXEnd - AxisXStart) + AxisXStart
fy(point) = (word(point,2)-word($Axes[3],2))/(word($Axes[2],2)-word($Axes[3],2))*(AxisYEnd - AxisYStart) + AxisYStart

# get point
bind Button1 'if (|$Axes|<4) { set print $Axes append } else { set print $Data append }; \
              print MOUSE_X, MOUSE_Y; set print; replot'

# reset axis points
bind 0 'set print $Axes; print AxesHeader; set print; replot'

# remove all data points
bind x 'set print $Data; print DataHeader; set print; replot'

# remove last data point
bind c 'if (|$Data|>2) {array A[|$Data|]; do for [i=2:|$Data|-1] { A[i]=$Data[i] }; \
        set print $Data; do for [i=1:|A|-1] { print A[i] }; } \
        else {set print $Data; print DataHeader; }; set print; replot'

# save data to file
bind s 'set print DATAFILE; print $Data[1]; \
        do for [i=2:|$Data|] { print sprintf("%g %g", fx($Data[i]), fy($Data[i])) }; \
        set print; pause -1 sprintf("Data saved to: %s",DATAFILE)'

plot IMAGE binary filetype=auto origin=(0,0) dx=1 dy=1 with rgbimage, \
     $Axes u 1:2 w l lw 2 lc "blue" noautoscale, \
     $Data u 1:2 w p pt 7 lc "red" noautoscale
### end of script
```

**Input:** `Superconductivity.png`

[image]

**Procedure:** (Screen capture from wxt terminal)

[image]

**Result:** `Superconductivity.dat`

```
# Temperature Resistance
4.3696 0.130726
4.3328 0.126117
4.232 0.113966
4.20241 0.00157884
4.19248 0.000406976
4.18307 0.000751641
```